# Nested Django Forms: 'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with'

Tags: python, html, django, forms, nested-forms

So i've looked around and it seems nobody has had the same problem that I am having to cause this seemingly common error. I am rendering some forms in my html as follows:

```
<form method="post" action="">
{{ tags_formset.management_form }}

<!-- code displaying this formset -->
...
<!-- -->

    <form method="post" action="">
        {{ add_all_form.management_form }}
        {{ add_all_form.addTagsToAll }}
        <input type="submit" value="Add To Displayed Applicants" />
    </form>

    <form method="post" action="">
        {{ remove_all_form.management_form }}
        {{ remove_all_form.removeTagsFromAll }}
        <input type="submit" value="Remove From Displayed Applicants" />
    </form>
    <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" />
</form>
```

When i did not have the two inner forms the formset is displayed correctly and the submit button works to submit the form. When i added the 2nd two forms a couple of problems occured:

-The submit button stopped working (though pressing enter while one of the formset's fields is selected still submits the form

-The add_all_form's submit works and it functions propperly (not a problem but interesting concerning the next point...)

-The remove_all_form does not work ad throughs the 'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with' validation error.

Here is the views.py code that creats the forms:

```
    TagsFormSet = formset_factory(TagsForm, formset=TagFormSet, extra=applicantQuery.count())
    if request.method == 'POST':
        tags_formset = TagsFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='tags', applicants=applicantQuery)
        add_all_form = TagAddAllForm(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='addForm', applicants=applicantQuery)
        remove_all_form = TagRemoveAllForm(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='removeForm', applicants=applicantQuery)
        redirect = False
        if tags_formset.is_valid():
            for tagForm in tags_formset.forms:
                if 'tags' in tagForm.cleaned_data:
                    tagForm.saveTags()
                if 'removeTags' in tagForm.cleaned_data:
                    tagForm.deleteTags()                        
            redirect = True
        if add_all_form.is_valid():
            if 'addTagsToAll' in add_all_form.cleaned_data:
                add_all_form.saveTagsToAll()
            redirect = True
        if remove_all_form.is_valid():
            if 'removeTagsFromAll' in remove_all_form.cleaned_data:
                remove_all_form.deleteTagsFromAll()
            redirect = True
        if redirect:
            return http.HttpResponseRedirect('')
    else:
        initForms = []
        tags_formset = TagsFormSet(prefix='tags', applicants=applicantQuery)
        add_all_form = TagAddAllForm(prefix='addForm', applicants=applicantQuery)
        remove_all_form = TagRemoveAllForm(prefix='removeForm', applicants=applicantQuery)
```

I literally can not figure out what is going wrong. I don't know why the add_all_form works when the remove_all_form does not, as i basically copy and pasted everything involved (if you need  i can post the code from the Forms.py file but I don't think the problem is there...)

Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use only one `<form>` tag. You can have as many submit button as you want here and can display as many forms as you want, but all should be inside a single `<form>` tag.

Then all the management data will be sent properly in form submit and your issue should be fixed.

```
<form method="post" action="">
{{ tags_formset.management_form }}

<!-- code displaying this formset -->
...
<!-- -->


    {{ add_all_form.management_form }}
    {{ add_all_form.addTagsToAll }}
    <input type="submit" value="Add To Displayed Applicants" />


>
    {{ remove_all_form.management_form }}
    {{ remove_all_form.removeTagsFromAll }}
    <input type="submit" value="Remove From Displayed Applicants" />
<input type="submit" value="Save Changes" />
```

Your view can remain as it is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It worked perfectly. I would never have thought that I shouldn't put form tags for each form. It just seems like something you WOULD do so I didn't even question it. Thanks again!